# SQLServer object_id for indices?

Tags: sql-server, internals

Each object in database has its own object_id.

We can find the listing of objects and their object_ids either in sys.objects, or in view for specific types (sys.tables, sys.key_contraints, ... ).

Now my question is do indices have their own object_ids? From what I have found it seems not. If not, then why not? It looks like any other object (PK,FK, ... ) to me. Even default constraints have their own object_id.

Thanks for clarifications. This is "internals" question, I am not trying to achieve anything in particular, I just want to understand why things are as they are.

Comment: No they don't have their own object id. This is only relevant for items with metadata entries in `sys.objects` (or the associated base tables to be more accurate).

Comment: And object names in there need to be unique within a particular schema so the absence from there is quite beneficial for avoiding  collisions but does mean that currently we don't get the `create_date` for indexes stored anywhere.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok, got that, thanks. I can create IDX that has the same name like say PK constraint on other table. But I still dont understand the underlying principle, why index has no metadata entries? You yourself point-out that some of them would be useful (create data, modify date, ...). And even more so I think it can only add to confusion that you can name it like other objects...:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are unique on (object_id, index_id). That is all of the indexes for a given table will have the same object_id in sys.indexes, but will have a different index_id.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it does not really answer my question "why".